# Find the process that is shutting down or killing a program or service in Linux

Tags: services, process, postfix, monitoring, monit

In my situation, Postfix mysteriously shuts itself down: postfix/postfix-script stopping the Postfix mail system

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04, when I run

```
service postfix start
```

It starts up, but the a few minutes later shuts down.

```
May 22 09:10:15 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/postfix-script[12849]: starting the Postfix mail system
May 22 09:10:15 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/master[12851]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
May 22 09:11:41 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/postfix-script[12960]: stopping the Postfix mail system
May 22 09:11:41 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/master[12851]: terminating on signal 15
May 22 09:11:53 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/postfix-script[13167]: starting the Postfix mail system
May 22 09:11:53 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/master[13169]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
May 22 09:14:12 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/postfix-script[14044]: stopping the Postfix mail system
May 22 09:14:12 coenraad-Latitude-E5550 postfix/master[13169]: terminating on signal 15
```

I've enabled the service with:

```
sudo update-rc.d postfix enable
```

There is plenty of free memory and nothing else that seems related in any logs.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought that I somehow managed to install postfix without configuring it. The problem seemed to be solved by:

```
dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

I figured this out with the command:

```
lastcomm --debug
```

after each shut down, and I found:

```
CURRENT REC: systemd.postins |v3|     0.00|     0.00|    21.00|     0|     0|  4628.00|     0.00|   13513|   13305|     |       0|pts/11  |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
systemd.postins        root     pts/11     0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: systemctl       |v3|     1.00|     0.00|    21.00|     0|     0| 73472.00|     0.00|   13514|   13513|S    |       0|pts/11  |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
systemctl        S     root     pts/11     0.01 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: (sd-executor)   |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     1.00|     0|     0|226496.00|     0.00|   13516|       1|SF   |       0|__      |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
(sd-executor)    SF    root     __         0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: systemd-sysv-ge |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     1.00|     0|     0| 61832.00|     0.00|   13532|   13516|S    |       0|__      |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
systemd-sysv-ge  S     root     __         0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: postfix-instanc |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     1.00|     0|     0|  4628.00|     0.00|   13519|   13516|S    |       0|__      |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
postfix-instanc  S     root     __         0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: postconf        |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     0.00|     0|     0| 76928.00|     0.00|   13535|   13519|     |       0|__      |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
postconf               root     __         0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT REC: systemd-rc-loca |v3|     0.00|     0.00|     1.00|     0|     0| 61816.00|     0.00|   13529|   13516|S    |       0|__      |Wed May 22 09:13:02 2019
systemd-rc-loca  S     root     __         0.00 secs Wed May 22 09:13
```

Which made it look like it's trying to do some interactive configuration in the background - which presumably it was programmed to abort if its not in an interactive session. Manual configuration seemed to flip the necessary switches.

The saga continued... I checked cron of different users, auditd log, system logs for OOM killer, I just could not find the culprit.

What eventually saved me from insanity, was Ciro Santilli's answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux - which I monitored until it stopped, where it logged this:

```
20119   2102 /etc/init.d/postfix stop
```

And then

```
$ ps auxf|grep 2102
root      2102  0.0  0.0  40820  3940 ?        S    May28   2:58 /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

There we have it. The culprit is monit.